# Pass varying number of inputs to a function as a list in r (application: plot_summs)

Tags: r, list

I am trying to make a significant number of plots in a uniform style using plot_summs. I would like to have a function that is a wrapper and can generate the plots as part of a loop. However, the number of models included varies, and I cannot figure out how to pass a varying number of models to plot_summs.

Using the example from the plot_summs documentation, modified to illustrate my problem:

```
states <- as.data.frame(state.x77)
fit1 <- lm(Income ~ Frost + Illiteracy + Murder +
             Population + Area + `Life Exp` + `HS Grad`,
           data = states, weights = runif(50, 0.1, 3))
fit2 <- lm(Income ~ Frost + Illiteracy + Murder +
             Population + Area + `Life Exp` + `HS Grad`,
           data = states, weights = runif(50, 0.1, 3))
fit3 <- lm(Income ~ Frost + Illiteracy + Murder +
             Population + Area + `Life Exp` + `HS Grad`,
           data = states, weights = runif(50, 0.1, 3))

# I can pass a varying number of models to plot_summs, and it will work fine:
plot_summs(fit1, fit2, fit3,
           coefs = c("Frost Days" = "Frost", "% Illiterate" = "Illiteracy",
                     "Murder Rate" = "Murder"),
           scale = TRUE, robust = TRUE)
plot_summs(fit1, fit2,
           coefs = c("Frost Days" = "Frost", "% Illiterate" = "Illiteracy",
                     "Murder Rate" = "Murder"),
           scale = TRUE, robust = TRUE)

# However, in order to have a wrapper function that can flexibly plot a varying
# number of models, I have the models stored as a list:
variablenumberinputs <- list(fit1,fit2)

# I can plot from this list as long as I know the number of items in it:
plot_summs(variablenumberinputs[[1]],variablenumberinputs[[2]],recursive = FALSE),
           coefs = c("Frost Days" = "Frost", "% Illiterate" = "Illiteracy",
                     "Murder Rate" = "Murder"),
           scale = TRUE, robust = TRUE)

# But I cannot figure out a version of "unlist" or similar that will let me 
# do this without hard-coding the number of models. Eg, the following fails:
plot_summs(unlist(variablenumberinputs,recursive = FALSE),
           coefs = c("Frost Days" = "Frost", "% Illiterate" = "Illiteracy",
                     "Murder Rate" = "Murder"),
           scale = TRUE, robust = TRUE)

# note that just passing the list to the function results in a plot, but the plot is incorrect.
```

Comment: Just use do.call().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `do.call`

```
do.call(plot_summs, c(variablenumberinputs, 
            list(coefs = c("Frost Days" = "Frost",
               "% Illiterate" = "Illiteracy",
                 "Murder Rate" = "Murder"),
       scale = TRUE, robust = TRUE)))
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  When I run it this way, it does not seem to register the coefs variable - ie, the outcome is the same as if I had run "plot_summs(fit1,fit2,scale=TRUE,robust=TRUE)", and it just defaults to using all the coefficients in the model.  So it's close, but not quite the same as what was intended?

Comment: @neuropsych sorry, couldn't test your code as `states` was not found

Comment: oops, sorry! The definition was eaten by my ``` to turn it into a code block - should be fixed now

Comment: @neuropsych can you specify the package for `plot_summs`

Comment: it's 
plot_summs {jtools}

Documentation currently here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/jtools/versions/2.1.2/topics/plot_summs

Comment: @neuropsych i missed a `list` wrapper.  Please check the update